# WPF - Using Windows Media Import

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use the Windows Media Import API in a WPF Application I have added a reference to the Windows Runtime but still failing to get it to run. Any ideas what the missing references may be?

[image]

[image: Packages]

Comment: I suspect you're targeting an _ancient_ version of .NET Framework. Please post your `.csproj`.

Comment: try add ``using System.Collections.Generic`` to the ...xaml.cs... The error says, it misses   [IReadOnlyList<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.csproj` is targeting an **ancient and unsupported** version of .NET Framework, specifically: .NET Framework 4.0 which dates back to 2010, which is before the `IReadOnly...<T>` collection interface types were added to .NET in .NET Framework 4.5 in 2012.

As it's 2021, you should now be targeting either .NET Framework 4.8 - or .NET 5. As porting to .NET 5 is a large undertaking, just update to .NET 4.8:

So change this:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to this:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Comment: Thanks Dai still some errors to work through since updating to v4.8

Comment: debugged successfully now as per screenshot